# How to get outgoing call duration in real time?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [It's possible to get outgoing call duration during call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959128/its-possible-to-get-outgoing-call-duration-during-call)

I need to show real-time outgoing call duration.

But I do not know when I should start timer.

I must start when get answer from other side.
I tried TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK -- but it's state is when
I press call-button..

OFFHOOK is the state when call is placed.
So we should be notified when the call is received.

How can we get that? 
Can You help me? When I should start count outgoing time?

Thanks

upd..

I think this data produces mobile operator server. And this server return call-duration and current balance after each outgoing call .
Maybe It's right?

I can't find any solution, but after each call value of call duration will be stored in db. We can get it by CallLog.Calls.DURATION
How this value populate field in db?

Comment: did you solve this problem? would also like to know the answer about incoming calls and not just outgoing calls.

Comment: +android developer No, unfortunately I don't have found correct solution..
I can get duration of the call only when call is finished.

Answer (score 4):

Using a content Observer to listen Call Logs content URI if it changed:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
CallLogObserver mObserver = new CallLogObserver(new Handler(), context);
contentResolver.registerContentObserver(
    Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls"), true, mObserver);
```

This is your CallLogObserver:

```
public class CallLogObserver extends ContentObserver {
    private Context context;

    public CallLogObserver(Handler handler, Context context) {
        super(handler);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        Log.i(TAG, "CallLogs Onhange()");
        try{
            Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
            if (c != null) {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    int type = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)));
                    /*
                     * increase call counter for outgoing call only
                     */
                    if (type == 2){
                        String number = c.getString(c
                                .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));

                        long duration = c.getLong(c
                                .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));

                                                    Log.i(TAG, "numer = " + number + " type = " + type + " duration = " + duration);

                                                }
                }
                c.close();
            }
            else
                Log.e(TAG,"Call Logs Cursor is Empty");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Error on onChange : "+ e.toString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: This doesn't get the duration in real time, the duration of the call is added to the log after the call is finished.

Comment: This is a decent solution but do not catch all exceptions, this is a really bad practice. `try .. catch` block is unnecessary unless the developer wants to add it explicitly

Comment: You can replace the hardcoded string `Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls")` with this reference from inside android library itself: `android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI`