# Outgoing call duration when it received

Tags: android

Can anybody tell me that how to get outgoing call duration when it received from other side in android.

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: MAY be this will help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959128/its-possible-to-get-outgoing-call-duration-during-call

Answer (score 0):

You should use [**android.provider.CallLog.Calls**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html). With this class you can get the content of the Call Log (**incoming, outgoing, missed calls**) which contains the duration of every call.

Here is [**a tutorial**](http://www.anddev.org/video-tut_-_querying_and_displaying_the_calllog-t169.html) about it.

Comment: Yes I used this class as String duration = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.duration.  but this is not giving any value of the duration. then how to use this class

Comment: Yes I used following permissions  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />     
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />