# Android get talked time for current call

Tags: android

I am looking for a way to get the time of an ended call, like when you call someone, and he answers, your phone starts counting the time, and when you hang up, Android shows you how much you talked this call, like 2:45 mins, I want to get that time, how can I do it?

Comment: This may be a duplicate (mods?). There is a similar discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982894/how-to-get-the-outgoing-call-duration-in-real-time

Comment: I need only the last call duration, not the durations for the whole CallLog